# How to deal with duplicate table name with db_select left join

Tags: migrations, database

Basically I have a db_select that has two left joins.  And will be calling up two table fields with the same name.  The fields have different data though, so I need to be able to have access to both in my results.  In a normal query I’d set this in the SELECT - how can i do the same in db_select

```
SELECT table1.column AS column1, table2.column AS column2
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
ON table1.column = table2.column
```

here's my code that i need to change

```
$query->leftjoin('migrate_map_emp', 'm', 'm.sourceid1 = i.ID');
$query->leftjoin('migrate_map_emplogo', 'ml', 'ml.sourceid1 = i.ID');

$query->fields('i', array('ID','Name'))
      ->fields('m', array('destid1'))
      ->fields('ml', array('destid1'));
```

[solved]

the above code works.  I did a 'drush_print_r'  on the rows returned at the second item is labelled ml_

[destid1] => 5
    [ml_destid1] => 2

Many thanks

Comment: You can also use the addField method to specify an aliased name name.

Comment: All the join methods return the new alias, you should use that for 'best practice' (potential collisions with other provided aliases are handled)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fetch data with `drupal db_select` as below code:-

```
$query= db_select('table1', 'column1');
$query->join('table2', 'column2', 'column1.column=column2.column'); 

$query=$query->fields('column1',array('column'))
       ->fields('column2',array('column'))       
       ->execute()->fetchAll();
```

For more information on db_select join queries click on this [link](https://www.drupal.org/node/310075)